# What does "wajib" mean in this hadith about doing ghusl in Jumua (Friday)?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, fiqh, uloom-al-hadith

In the book "**العرف الناشر**" ([pdf](http://www.archive.org/download/ibnacher/ibnacher.pdf)), fiqh Al-maliki, it is mentioned in page 240, that there is ijma (consensus) among the scholars that the prayer in Jumua is accepted with just regular wudu (ablution).

I guess this is derived from the hadith:

> مَنْ **تَوَضَّأَ فَأَحْسَنَ الْوُضُوءَ** ثُمَّ أَتَى الْجُمُعَةَ فَاسْتَمَعَ وَأَنْصَتَ غُفِرَ لَهُ مَا بَيْنَهُ وَبَيْنَ الْجُمُعَةِ وَزِيَادَةُ ثَلاَثَةِ أَيَّامٍ وَمَنْ مَسَّ الْحَصَى فَقَدْ لَغَا ‏"‏
>
> He who performed **ablution** well, then came to Friday prayer, listened (to the sermon), kept silence all (his sins) between that time and the next Friday would be forgiven with three days extra, and he who touched pebbles caused an interruption.
>
> [Sahih Muslim - The Book of Prayer - Friday](https://sunnah.com/muslim/7/38)

A similar [hadith](https://sunnah.com/muslim/7/37) exists in the same chapter with the wording "bath" instead of ablution. In the book they use this [hadith](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?bk_no=692&pid=347485&hid=1561) as evidence:

> مَنْ أَتَى الْجُمُعَةَ فَتَوَضَّأَ فَبِهَا وَنِعْمَتْ ، وَمَنِ اغْتَسَلَ فَالْغُسْلُ أَفْضَلُ

---

Now the hadith I am asking about is this:

> أَنَّ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ ‏ ‏ غُسْلُ يَوْمِ الْجُمُعَةِ **وَاجِبٌ** عَلَى كُلِّ مُحْتَلِمٍ
>
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) (p.b.u.h) said, "The taking of a bath on Friday is **compulsory** (wajib) for every male (Muslim) who has attained the age of puberty."
>
> [Sahih al-Bukhari  - Friday Prayer](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/11/4)

**Question:** What does "wajib" mean in this hadith about doing ghusl in Jumua (Friday)?

It is mentioned that doing ghusl is sunnah mo'akada, but not obligatory.
So I basically wonder what wajib means in the hadith if it really isn't "wajib" as in our terminology. *(i.e it is called sunnah mo'akada then it can't be called wajib or obligatory)*

*In this [hadith](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/11/7) Umar responds on a man who didn't do ghusl and indicates that it is obligatory by quoting the Prophet.*

**P.S**: *I've read Bin Baz (salafi scholar) answer about this, but I'd rather want to hear other opinions too, because his description wasn't very convincing... But if you use some of his arguments, then explaining them more, that is okay for me, but adding more scholarly opinions is preferable.*

Comment: قال ابن عبد البر : ليس المراد أنه فرض بل هو مئول أي واجب في السنة أو في المروءة أو في الأخلاق الجميلة كقول العرب : وجب حقك

Comment: http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?bk_no=52&ID=560&idfrom=1634&idto=1750&bookid=52&startno=3

Answer (score -1):

The word Wajib is said here just to mean it's literal meaning and it does not mean the Wajib in Sharia. And I'm not saying it on my own. I've just quoted the words of Shaykh Salih ibn Fouzan, as he has said:

> ومعنى قوله صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏"‏واجب‏"‏‏.‏ أي‏:‏ متأكد وليس معناه أنه فرض

**Translation:**
And the meaning of His (PBUH) saying "Wajib" is to stress upon it and it does not mean it's "Fardh".

You can check this link. 
[Islamway.net/fatwa](https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=/amp/s/ar.islamway.net/amp/fatwa/6238/%2525D8%2525AD%2525D8%2525AF%2525D9%25258A%2525D8%2525AB-%2525D8%2525BA%2525D8%2525B3%2525D9%252584-%2525D9%25258A%2525D9%252588%2525D9%252585-%2525D8%2525A7%2525D9%252584%2525D8%2525AC%2525D9%252585%2525D8%2525B9%2525D8%2525A9-%2525D9%252588%2525D8%2525A7%2525D8%2525AC%2525D8%2525A8-%2525D8%2525B9%2525D9%252584%2525D9%252589-%2525D9%252583%2525D9%252584-%2525D9%252585%2525D8%2525AD%2525D8%2525AA%2525D9%252584%2525D9%252585&ved=0ahUKEwi_y_v7oNzUAhVFM48KHTUcAmEQFgghMAM&usg=AFQjCNEj7_-YvPFLts3_n_tvVt9wFvUvFQ)

Comment: You are only quoting what I asked in my question.

Comment: You asked what does Wajib mean and I gave a link to the place which tells about the meaning of Wajib.